# Oaut2RestTemplate with client_credentials error (anonymous not allowed)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to access a web service which is protected by Spring Security using `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` (with Oauth2 `client_credentials`)

Following is the security configuration

```java
//Micoservice 1
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private DummyUserFilter dummyUserFilter;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(dummyUserFilter, LogoutFilter.class)
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/js/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

This application (Microservice 1) is to be accessed by another application (Microservice 2) with the `Oauth2RestTemplate`. Following is the `Oauth2RestTemplate` configuration.

```java
//MicroService 2
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("https://<UAA>/oauth/token");
        resourceDetails.setClientId("#####");
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret("#####");
        resourceDetails.setGrantType("client_credentials");
        resourceDetails.setTokenName("access_token");

        DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();

        OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);

        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

`Microservice 2` has various web services which use RestTemplate to access the protected web services of `Microservice 1`.

This always results in following exception

**Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)**

I have searched for this error and found that it's thrown in `AccessTokenProviderChain`

Here's the link from github for the relevant code

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/AccessTokenProviderChain.java#L89

```
if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
    if (!resource.isClientOnly()) {
        throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                "Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)");
    }
}
```

It seems that it doesn't allow anonymous user to get access to the Oauth2 token.

I have no intention of protecting the client application (Microservice 2) with Oauth2 and I must use `client_credentials` for the `Oauth2RestTemplate`, that's preconfigured.

**How can I stop Spring from blocking anonymous user from accessing token ?**

I have already tried to populate `SecurityContextHolder` with dummy authentication in case of anonymouse user, with no success. Even if I do succeed in doing so, it seems like a hack.

Comment: For now I have solved it by separating creation of `Oauth2RestTemplate` completely from Spring. If I create a bean for `Oauth2RestTemplate` or try to autowire it, Spring detects and tries to interfere with it. So I created my own singleton class for `Oauth2RestTemplate` which has nothing to with Spring, for now it works. However I'm looking forward to a real answer.

Comment: Have you tried defining the `restTemplate` bean of type `OAuth2RestTemplate` instead of `RestTemplate `, and `@autowire`ing , with `OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate `?
On the other hand, it doesn't make sense to throw `InsufficientAuthenticationException` if you are using `ClientCredentialResourceDetails` as it clearly returns `true` for `isClientOnly()` https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/grant/client/ClientCredentialsResourceDetails.java. Any chance other Bean in place?

Comment: Yes, I have used Oauth2RestTemplate, as you can see in the code I posted in the question, it throws the same error. I don't think there's another bean, for now it's working by creating custom singleton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and concluded that the `AccessTokenProvider` interface, which has multiple implementors is the culprit. By default, the `OAuth2RestTemplate` instantiates the `AccessTokenProviderChain` which tries to re-use the existing login context. However, if no such login exists, this is bound to fail. Try

```
restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider());
```

in your factory method. This uses a token provider which owns its credentials and doesn't reference the thread local `SecurityContextHolder` in its implementation at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try Enabling httpBasic() security in your 2nd microservice and login to it using default username ("user") and generated password by spring.

Comment: That would require the user to be known by Spring, however authentication mechanism required is `client_credential` which doesn't involve a user.

Comment: Sorry, Previously I mentioned 1st microservice. I corrected it as 2nd microservice. I edited my answer. Try login to 2nd microservice as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I will give it a try, but why would that be required?

Comment: As per my knowledge, That's because spring doesn't allow anonymous users to proceed with Oauth2.  "Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)"

Answer (score 0):

use AuthorizedFeignClient or AuthorizedUserFeignClient instead oauth2RestTemplate...